# How does one access the properties of a Javascript object in Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, serialization

I am accessing a Javascript object (which has a form similar to this: `{ 1 : "Option 1", 2 : "Option 2", 3 : "Option 3" }`) from Silverlight using code similar to the following:

```
dynamic window = HtmlPage.Window;
var options = window.GlobalObject.getDropdownItems();
```

Now, the problem is that `options` is now of type `ScriptObject`.  This wouldn't be a problem if I knew what the names of the properties of my Javascript object were (I could just do `options.GetProperty(1)` to get the label for the first option).  However, this won't work because I need *both* the values and the names of the options.  Is there some way to convert it to a `Dictionary<int, string>` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to change the input of the options?  If you are, this is what I would suggest.

Change the input of the values to something along these lines:

```
function getDropdownItems() {
    var items = [{ Value: 1, Name: "Option 1" }, { Value: 2, Name: "Option 2" }, { Value: 3, Name: "Option 3"}];
    return items;
}
```

Then in Silverlight you can easily convert it to a typed object.

```
public class Option
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void LoadOptions()
{
    dynamic window = HtmlPage.Window;
    var dynamicoptions = window.getDropdownItems();

    ScriptObject scriptObject = dynamicoptions as ScriptObject;

    if (scriptObject != null)
    {
        var options = scriptObject.ConvertTo<Option[]>();
        if (options != null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I've found this is the easiest way to work with javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem.  First of all, I added a Javascript function called `getKeysOfObject`, which looks like this:

```
var getKeysOfObject = function (o)
{
    var keys = [], i;
    for (i in o) {
        keys.push(i);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Then I used that function to determine what the keys of my object were.  From there, it wasn't too difficult to get the information I needed from the object.

```
dynamic window = HtmlPage.Window;
dynamic options = window.getDropDownItems();
dynamic keys = window.getKeysOfObject(options);
int numKeys = Convert.ToInt32((double)keys.length);

for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; ++i)
{
    if (options[keys[i]].GetType() == typeof(ScriptObject))
    {
        optionDictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
            Convert.ToInt32((string)keys[i]),
            (string)options[keys[i]]);
    }
}
```

The reason for checking the type of the actual property of the object is that silverlight was adding a weird `$__slid` property to the object.